# Make a script in home to execute with sudo rights

Tags: shell-script, sudo

I'd like to execute a script in `~` with a command that needs elevated rights. This example should suffice:

```
cp /etc/AAA/* /etc/BBB/
```

Now if that copying script would be started in, say, `scripty.sh` with the `+x` bit set, it wouldn't work.

This is actually about exchanging the `xbacklight -set $brightness_night`-commands like `ddcutil setvcp 10 70` in a script to [control screen brightness](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Redshift#Use_real_screen_brightness).

How can I script this to avoid entering my password each time the brightness is changed? Or would this be the easiest way still?

Comment: Umm... is `sudo` not sufficient?

Comment: What is the question?  The common way to execute a script or executable requiring root permissions is with `sudo script`.

Comment: Also possible: Make the script use `sudo cp …`.

Comment: @maulinglawns Must admit I haven't tried that.

Comment: @user4556274 I edited the op.